# SPNEGO with Apache HTTP Components Fluid API

Tags: java, authorization, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents, spnego

How can SPNEGO authorization scheme be specified for a request using [Apache HTTP Components](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) Fluent API?

There does not seem to be a way to set
`org.apache.http.client.config.AuthSchemes.SPNEGO` onto either
`org.apache.http.client.fluent.Request` or
`org.apache.http.client.fluent.Executor`.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'specifying SPNEGO'? HttpClient with or without fluent facade always picks up the auth scheme it considers the most secure out of available challenges presented by the server. SPNEGO is considered the most secure and always gets picked up by default.

Comment: With regular API, SPNEGO authorization is specified as: 
`client.getAuthSchemes().register(AuthPolicy.SPNEGO, new SPNegoSchemeFactory(true))` on `DefaultHttpClient` reference. How can this be done using fluent API?

Comment: SPNEGO is enabled by default since HC 4.1. It is not needed to register it explicitly